# Customise Touch Bar in Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: macos, ms-office, touch-bar

The February 2017 updates for Microsoft Office 2016 include Touch Bar support on the new MacBook Pros. But the defaults aren't very usable, and I can't find an option to customise the Touch Bar layout as is found on other apps with TouchBar support. Is there any way to customise the Touch Bar in Office 2016?

Comment: before I updated my ms. word, there was a print option on the touch bar when I click command+P. but now, I can't find the print option on the touch bar. any solutions?

Comment: Every time I try to delete something in MSWord, I end up activating Siri. This is maddening enough to make me look for another word processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an option at this point in time. 
As an office insider, I recently sent a feature  request to them. If you'd like to send a feature request, just click the :) in the top right corner and go from there.

Comment: Yeah. The touch bar feature is really nicely implemented for PowerPoint. But strange that the "start presentation" button is missing ;)